# custom uitableheader view

Tags: uitableview, frame

I want to put a custom view inside my uitableviewheader, this custom view has an UILabel and a UITextView, the label have a fixed size while uitextview need to change depending the content of uitextview.
For doing it I use this code:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 100;
}
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,100)];
headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];


NSString *userString = [user username];
UILabel *userLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
[userLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[userLabel setText:userString];
userLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[headerView addSubview:userLabel];

UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 60)];
NSString *postString = [currentPost objectForKey:@"postTextKey"];
textView.text = postString;

[headerView addSubview:textView];

CGRect frame = textView.frame;
frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;
textView.frame = frame;

frame = headerView.frame;
frame.size.height = textView.frame.size.height+40;
headerView.frame = frame;

self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = headerView.frame;

return headerView;

}
```

the problem is that if the headerview have the correct height the tableviewheader is wrong. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `tableHeaderView` is different from section header view (`headerViewForSection:`)
2) If you want to change the height you specify it in the `- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` method and then call the `reloadData` method if the height changes.

Note: you don't want to do that too often.

Comment: thank you, I have to create my custom view and then use self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;!

Comment: Yes. That is if you want to use the table header. A UITableView can have one table header for the entire table, but it can have many sections, and each section can have a header.

Comment: yes, my problem is that I have confused the tableheader and the header of section! thank you!